# Team foundation Server Git - Add warning message before commiting to a branch

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

We are using Team foundation server foundation Git, to centralise our projects.
Recently by mistake, I checked into a "parent" branch which we created instead of a "Child" branch which is created from "parent" branch.

Generally, we create a "Child" branch for each task and create a pull request to "Parent" branch, for the review, merge and test.

Can you please tell me if there is a possibility to create warning message that we can set to "Parent" branch, which can warn us before accidentally committing changes to "Parent" branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TFS branch policies for that.

> Branch policies help teams protect their important branches of development. Policies enforce your team's code quality and change management standards.

And, specifically for your case,

> After you set up a branch policy, you cannot directly push changes to the branch. Changes to the branch are only made through pull requests.

This is [official documentation (with pictures!)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies?view=vsts) on how to configure branch policies.

Comment: :Thank you for the reply and link.It gave a very good idea about setting policies for branch.

Comment: Came across Branch Permissions,while going through Branch policies.I think we can also use branch permissions > Access control summary>Contribute, setting it to Remove will also help a user to from comitting to a specific branch.